# Handling configuration values in mix

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am currently struggling to handle config values in mix (particularly when running tests). This is my scenario:

- i have a client library, with some common config values (key, secret, region).
- i want to test what happens when there's no region value setup
- i have no `test.exs` file in `/config`

I'm currently doing it like this (and this doesn't work).
Module being tested (simplified):

```
defmodule Streamex.Client do
  @api_region Application.get_env(:streamex, :region)
  @api_key Application.get_env(:streamex, :key)
  @api_secret Application.get_env(:streamex, :secret)
  @api_version "v1.0"
  @api_url "api.getstream.io/api"

  def full_url(%Request{} = r) do
    url = <<"?api_key=", @api_key :: binary>>
  end
end
```

Test:

```
setup_all do
  Streamex.start
  Application.put_env :streamex, :key, "KEY"
  Application.put_env :streamex, :secret, "SECRET"
  Application.put_env :streamex, :secret, ""
end
```

What happens when running `mix test` is that the main module, which sets attributes from those values, throws the following error since it can't find valid values:

```
lib/streamex/client.ex:36: invalid literal nil in <<>>
```

I'm still starting so this may seem obvious, but i can't find a solution after reading the docs.

Comment: Can you please include the exact error message in the question?

Comment: @Dogbert Updated the question including more context

Comment: Just discovered more about problem(s) in my code, feel like there's some interesting catches for noobs like me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're storing the return value of `Application.get_env` in a module attribute, which is evaluated at *compile* time. If you change the values in your tests, it won't be reflected in the module attribute -- you'll always get the value that's present when `mix` compiled that module, which includes evaluating `config/config.exs` and all the modules that `mix` compiled before compiling that module. The fix is to move the variables that can be changed to a function and call those functions whenever they're used:

```
defmodule Streamex.Client do
  @api_version "v1.0"
  @api_url "api.getstream.io/api"

  def full_url(%Request{} = r) do
    url = <<"?api_key=", api_key :: binary>>
  end

  def api_region, do: Application.get_env(:streamex, :region)
  def api_key, do: Application.get_env(:streamex, :key)
  def api_secret, do: Application.get_env(:streamex, :secret)
end
```

Note that if this is a library and you want the users of the library to be able to configure the values in their config files, you *have* to use function calls at runtime as the dependencies of an app are compiled before the app.

Comment: Not sure if following SO policies, but i would like to open a bounty and give that to your answer - which already nailed it. To get the prize, it would be cool for me and others if you expanded on the last point you're making, more precisely: by using function calls to read config values, i'm actually forcing my users to _always_ use configuration. Injection of those values would be impossible by other means. This could be problematic when running asynchronous tests. Is this idiomatic in your opinion? Thanks so much.

Comment: "Injection of those values would be impossible by other means." What other means? `Application.put_env` would work perfectly fine. (There's no need for any bounty -- I have enough already. :))

Comment: If i run async tests, and put an `Application.put_env` in one of them, can i still rest sure that i'll be reading the right config value in every test?

Comment: Yeah, that'll be a problem in async tests. get_env/put_env are similar to global variables in other languages. You would probably need to accept an extra optional config map in each function that requires access to api key/secret/region and use the value present in that, falling back to get_env.

Comment: Thank you so much, you made clear a lot of things. I would upvote again if possible :)

Comment: Some parts of my answer are possibly wrong: it looks like it's possible to read main app's config from a dependency with some force recompiling hacks like https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/9e70b7713cc963ccfd17ae8f100ce5615b6dbadc/lib/plug/mime.ex#L18-L19. I'll update that part of my answer when I get a chance to investigate.

Comment: Last time I had similar issue. Upvote from my side as well. Nicely done Dogbert.

Comment: @Dogbert Just to add a final note, I ended up with "if not specified, read the value from config" approach. I feel like messing with compilation is not as elegant as allowing injection of values. I'm now having a client structure with key, secret and region fields which gets passed all around. This makes tests clearer in my opinion, while ensuring async coherence. Still it's interesting to know if there are some hacks around.